# remove / hide all stepTitles in angular-archwizard step

Tags: css, angular

I am using angular-archwizard. PFA: image I don't want these highlighted stepTitles OR i just want to hide/ remove those stepTitles. I have tried passing blank string in "stepTitle" field but it not worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your CSS:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

Or if it doesn't work for you, try this one:

```
::ng-deep aw-wizard-navigation-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  // or
  display: none;
}
```